# How do I properly send an early http error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)?

Tags: c#, http

I'm using raw TCP sockets. I can send 200/404/302 without a problem.

If I serve 413 like a normal request it works just fine

```
"HTTP/1.1 413\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;\r\nContent-Length: 7\r\n\r\nToo big"
```

However in the http 1/1 rfc it says I may close the connection before processing the request https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.14

> ## Request Entity Too Large
>
> The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity is larger than the server is willing or able to process. The server MAY close the connection to prevent the client from continuing the request.

However when I serve the results and don't process the entire request both firefox and chrome will show a connection error. When I send the results THEN READ THE REQUEST it will work. The browsers seem to not process what I send them until I read the entire stream which defeats the point.

Or maybe I'm sending it wrong. How am I suppose to send the 413? I send the string above, flush the socket, sleep for 100 milliseconds, close the connection, sleep for another 100 milliseconds then restart.

Comment: HTTP 1.0 is stream mode and HTTP 1.1 is chink mode.  The RFC is saying the maximum size of the response can be set by the server and if the max is exceeded the server can close the connection.  With 1.0 you will always have the connection closed if you exceeded the max.  With chunk mode you can specify the chunk size so it is less than the max so you can get the entire response in multiple chunks.

Comment: @jdweng: How do I specify the chunk size?

Comment: See RFC para 3.6.1 : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html

Comment: @jdweng: That's about the server sending data to client. I'm talking about when the client (browser) uploads a large file (post body) and the server doesn't support that size and wants to give an error early

Comment: You could use multiple ports.  Send size in one connection and the data in a second connection on a different port.

Answer (score 1):

A request and response exchange isn't considered complete until both the request data is fully received and the response fully sent. So the only way to send a valid `413` response is to read (and presumably discard) the full request body, as well as sending the 413 as soon as possible as it appears you are doing.

If you send the 413 immediately, it's up to the client to detect that early or not. I think most clients will just continue uploading the request though.

Alternatively, you may close the connection which is how you can stop the client from sending the whole message. But then, the HTTP request and response is not complete, and clients may show a connection error rather than the 413.

So: if you want to stop clients uploading data then close the connection. If you want clients to get a nice valid 413 response then consume the whole request.